# Python can only use variable once

Tags: python

I am playing around a bit with Python but came across some behaviour I can't readily explain.

When I define a map (dictionary I believe it's called in Python) to the top of my file, then when running the code twice, I get an array saying `String index out of range`. But when I define the map/dictionary inside my method, then it runs without a problem over and over.

To try and give a minimal example. This is the main method I am running

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
while True:
    hex = convert_binary_to_hex([1,1,1,1])
    print(hex)
```

This will call a function that will split the file into correct parts etc. All trivial things. 
Once I have the result in decimal (so `[1,1,1,1]` is turned into 15), I call this function which is where the error occurs:

```
def decimal_sum_chunk(chunk):
    chunk.reverse()
    sum = 0
    for i in range(len(chunk)):
        sum += chunk[i] * (2**i)

return digit_to_hex(sum)

def digit_to_hex(number):
    if number < 10:
        return str(number)

    # else we look up the value in the map
    return hex[number]
```

The error occurs when I have hex defined at the top of the file like this:

`hex = {10 : 'A', 11 : 'B', 12 : 'C', 13 : 'D', 14 : 'E', 15 : 'F'}`

I can use the exact same code but change the last function by defining the map in there and it will work perfectly:

```
def digit_to_hex(number):
    hex = {10 : 'A', 11 : 'B', 12 : 'C', 13 : 'D', 14 : 'E', 15 : 'F'}

    if number < 10:
        return str(number)

    # else we look up the value in the map
    return hex[number]
```

I have created this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DylanMeeus/9004727b8506ceb3b8895093067f2ca2) which shows the full code when it is *not working*. To make it work, I can just place the `hex` map/dictionary inside the function.

Thanks!

Comment: You're overwriting the value of `hex` with `hex = convert_binary_to_hex([1,1,1,1])`... (which returns a string)

Comment: @Rawing damn.. yeah, sometimes you need an extra pair of eyes on something. Thanks!

Comment: Fid you try the same program by using `globals hex` inside the function?